# Adding code for create attributes in category general information Tab in adminsidde error

Tags: adminhtml, category-attribute

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\header.phml adding code for create attributes in category general tab i adding this code

```
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'label'=> 'Your attribute label',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'your_attribute_code', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

then i display error in magento category tab

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Boolean' not found in \magento\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146
```

**after remove this code after display this error** what can do to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am finding this answer in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718954/varien-data-form-element-int-not-found-in-magento

in this link it working for me. i do 
 2 down vote

Try to change `'input' => 'int', to 'input' => 'text',`. If this register is already on table, go to `eav_attribute` search for your row and change the field `frontend_input` to `text`.

Comment: also i am making one example in blog if some one help him http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2014/09/create-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento.html check out.